# The isUserInteraction setting is not taking effect when UIView.animate() call starts

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, race-condition

I recently noticed a race condition between two button clicks on the same view. To quickly reproduce this issue, we could use the following codes --

```
class LandingView: UIView {
    
    private var blackButton: UIButton!
    private var redButton: UIButton!
    private var testView1: UIView!
    private var testView2: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        blackButton = UIButton()
        self.addSubview(blackButton)

        // sorry I am using Snapkit here for a quick POC. but if you
        // just draw any button, it should reproduce the problem as well.
        blackButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.height.equalTo(30)
            maker.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
            maker.left.equalToSuperview().offset(30)
            maker.right.equalTo(self.snp.centerX).offset(-30)
        }
        blackButton.backgroundColor = .black
        blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showView1), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        redButton = UIButton()
        self.addSubview(redButton)
        redButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.height.equalTo(30)
            maker.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
            maker.left.equalTo(self.snp.centerX).offset(30)
            maker.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-30)
        }
        redButton.backgroundColor = .red
        redButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showView2), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented"); }

    @objc func showView1() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.redButton.isEnabled = false
        self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before constructing testview1")

        testView1 = UIView()
        self.addSubview(testView1)
        testView1.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.size.equalToSuperview()
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        testView1.backgroundColor = .black
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        testView1.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.width.equalTo(100)
            maker.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        backButton.backgroundColor = .white
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quitView1), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        testView1.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before animating testview1")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.testView1.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { _ in
            NSLog("DEBUG -- finished animating testview1")
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.redButton.isEnabled = true
            self.blackButton.isEnabled = true
        })
    }
    
    @objc func quitView1() {
        testView1.removeFromSuperview()
        testView1 = nil
    }
    
    @objc func showView2() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.redButton.isEnabled = false
        self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before constructing testview2")

        testView2 = UIView()
        self.addSubview(testView2)
        testView2.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.size.equalToSuperview()
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        testView2.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        testView2.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.width.equalTo(100)
            maker.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        backButton.backgroundColor = .white
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quitView2), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        testView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before animating testview2")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.testView2.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { _ in
            NSLog("DEBUG -- finished animating testview2")
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.redButton.isEnabled = true
            self.blackButton.isEnabled = true
        })
    }
    
    @objc func quitView2() {
        testView2.removeFromSuperview()
        testView2 = nil
    }
}
```

The experiment is pretty easy -- you could just click these two buttons at the same time after running this view in a view controller, and you will see two animations happens at the same time for displaying the black/red view.

So my expectation is that since I am calling `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, I am not expecting that the other one happens, since that is an unexpected race to me. But somehow the `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` call is invalidated within a shot window on the UIView.animate() call -- of course, if we do not set the `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in the completion handler, then the whole UI freezes, meaning the `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` call is working for most of the time.

Also the log is somewhat proving the theory. If we click the button at around the same time, we will see the following log sequence, and then we will have view1 overlaying view1 overlaying the testView, and the appearence of testview1 means that the `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` together with the call to set blackButton/redButton `isEnabled = false` not working properly, since the other button is still reactive to the click.

```
DEBUG -- before constructing testview2
DEBUG -- before animating testview2
DEBUG -- before constructing testview1
DEBUG -- before animating testview1
DEBUG -- finished animating testview1
DEBUG -- finished animating testview2
```

Does anyone have an idea on why the race could happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a "race" condition... you've set your button actions to `.touchUpInside`.

So, if you touch and hold on the black button, then **tap** (touch and release) on the red button, the black button is already "active" and waiting for the touch-up. Trying to disable it *after* it is already active won't work.

One approach would be to create two Bool vars:

```
private var blackButtonTapped: Bool = false
private var redButtonTapped: Bool = false
```

Then the first thing you do in each `showView` func would be:

```
@objc func showView1() {
    blackButtonTapped = true
    if redButtonTapped {
        return
    }
    self.redButton.isEnabled = false
    self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
    // ... continue with showView1 code
}

@objc func showView2() {
    redButtonTapped = true
    if blackButtonTapped {
        return
    }
    self.redButton.isEnabled = false
    self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
    // ... continue with showView2 code
}
```

Then when you `quit` your other views, re-enable the buttons:

```
private func reEnableButtons() -> Void {
    blackButton.isEnabled = true
    redButton.isEnabled = true
    blackButtonTapped = false
    redButtonTapped = false
}
```

Here's a full modified version of your `LandingView` class:

```
class LandingView: UIView {
    
    private var blackButton: UIButton!
    private var redButton: UIButton!
    private var testView1: UIView!
    private var testView2: UIView!
    
    private var blackButtonTapped: Bool = false
    private var redButtonTapped: Bool = false

    // use a common init function to allow adding this view
    //  in Storyboard / Interface Builder

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        blackButton = UIButton()
        self.addSubview(blackButton)
        
        // sorry I am using Snapkit here for a quick POC. but if you
        // just draw any button, it should reproduce the problem as well.
        blackButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.height.equalTo(30)
            maker.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
            maker.left.equalToSuperview().offset(30)
            maker.right.equalTo(self.snp.centerX).offset(-30)
        }
        blackButton.backgroundColor = .black
        blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showView1), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        redButton = UIButton()
        self.addSubview(redButton)
        redButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.height.equalTo(30)
            maker.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
            maker.left.equalTo(self.snp.centerX).offset(30)
            maker.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-30)
        }
        redButton.backgroundColor = .red
        redButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showView2), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func showView1() {
        blackButtonTapped = true
        if redButtonTapped {
            return
        }
        self.redButton.isEnabled = false
        self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before constructing testview1")
        
        testView1 = UIView()
        self.addSubview(testView1)
        testView1.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.size.equalToSuperview()
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        testView1.backgroundColor = .black
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        testView1.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.width.equalTo(100)
            maker.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        backButton.backgroundColor = .white
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quitView1), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        testView1.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before animating testview1")
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.testView1.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { _ in
        })
    }
    
    @objc func quitView1() {
        testView1.removeFromSuperview()
        testView1 = nil
        reEnableButtons()
    }
    
    @objc func showView2() {
        redButtonTapped = true
        if blackButtonTapped {
            return
        }
        self.redButton.isEnabled = false
        self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before constructing testview2")
        
        testView2 = UIView()
        self.addSubview(testView2)
        testView2.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.size.equalToSuperview()
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        testView2.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        testView2.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.width.equalTo(100)
            maker.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        backButton.backgroundColor = .white
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quitView2), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        testView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before animating testview2")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.testView2.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { _ in
        })
    }
    
    @objc func quitView2() {
        testView2.removeFromSuperview()
        testView2 = nil
        reEnableButtons()
    }
    
    private func reEnableButtons() -> Void {
        blackButton.isEnabled = true
        redButton.isEnabled = true
        blackButtonTapped = false
        redButtonTapped = false
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Here's another modification. This one disables the "other button" on the `.touchDown` event (instead of using Bool flags to control code execution flow):

```
class SecondLandingView: UIView {
    
    private var blackButton: UIButton!
    private var redButton: UIButton!
    private var testView1: UIView!
    private var testView2: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        blackButton = UIButton()
        self.addSubview(blackButton)
        
        // sorry I am using Snapkit here for a quick POC. but if you
        // just draw any button, it should reproduce the problem as well.
        blackButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.height.equalTo(30)
            maker.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
            maker.left.equalToSuperview().offset(30)
            maker.right.equalTo(self.snp.centerX).offset(-30)
        }
        blackButton.backgroundColor = .black
        blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.blackTouchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
        blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchUpOutside(_:)), for: .touchUpOutside)
        blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchUpOutside(_:)), for: .touchCancel)

        blackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDown(_:)), for: .touchDown)

        redButton = UIButton()
        self.addSubview(redButton)
        redButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.height.equalTo(30)
            maker.top.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
            maker.left.equalTo(self.snp.centerX).offset(30)
            maker.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-30)
        }
        redButton.backgroundColor = .red
        redButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.redTouchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
        redButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchUpOutside(_:)), for: .touchUpOutside)
        redButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchUpOutside(_:)), for: .touchCancel)

        redButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDown(_:)), for: .touchDown)

    }

    @objc func touchDown(_ sender: Any?) {
        guard let btn = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }
        if btn == blackButton {
            print("black touch down")
            redButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            print("red touch down")
            blackButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    
    @objc func touchUpOutside(_ sender: Any?) {
        guard let btn = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }
        if btn == blackButton {
            print("black touch up outside")
        } else {
            print("red touch up outside")
        }
        reEnableButtons()
    }
    
    @objc func blackTouchUpInside() {

        // redButton is already disabled in touchDown()
        self.redButton.isEnabled = false

        // red button tapped, so disable it
        self.blackButton.isEnabled = false

        NSLog("DEBUG -- before constructing testview1")
        
        testView1 = UIView()
        self.addSubview(testView1)
        testView1.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.size.equalToSuperview()
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        testView1.backgroundColor = .black
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        testView1.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.width.equalTo(100)
            maker.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        backButton.backgroundColor = .white
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quitView1), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        testView1.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before animating testview1")
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.testView1.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { _ in
        })
    }
    
    @objc func quitView1() {
        testView1.removeFromSuperview()
        testView1 = nil
        reEnableButtons()
    }
    
    @objc func redTouchUpInside() {
        
        // red button tapped, so disable it
        self.redButton.isEnabled = false
        
        // blackButton is already disabled in touchDown()
        //self.blackButton.isEnabled = false
        
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before constructing testview2")
        
        testView2 = UIView()
        self.addSubview(testView2)
        testView2.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.size.equalToSuperview()
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        testView2.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        testView2.addSubview(backButton)
        backButton.snp.makeConstraints{ (maker) in
            maker.center.equalToSuperview()
            maker.width.equalTo(100)
            maker.height.equalTo(100)
        }
        backButton.backgroundColor = .white
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(quitView2), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        testView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        NSLog("DEBUG -- before animating testview2")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.testView2.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { _ in
        })
    }
    
    @objc func quitView2() {
        testView2.removeFromSuperview()
        testView2 = nil
        reEnableButtons()
    }
    
    private func reEnableButtons() -> Void {
        blackButton.isEnabled = true
        redButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi DonMag, thanks for answering! I might not accept the answer for the following reasons -- 1. You are creating a Mutex in your code saying that if any of the red/black button is clicked, then we will return directly. This does not sound like an ideal solution though. 2. You are saying that self.redButton.isEnabled = false for example will not work, but indeed this works if you add some sleep after this operation. In my test, I found that this lock is released only when we have entered the UIView.animate() call, see the log sequence I have supplied in the latest description.

Comment: @user2870133 - well, not much different than setting the Bool `.isEnabled` flag. But, if you really don't want to do it that way, see the **Edit** to my answer.